# Restrict entering Spaces in TextBox in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my code have to allow numerical alphabets and special characters. but in my code not accepting the space and special characters except @.
Here is my code.

```
allowAlphaNumericSpace(e: any) {
var code = 'charCode' in e ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
if (
  !(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
  !(code >= 64 && code <= 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
  !(code > 96 && code < 123)
) {
  // lower alpha (a-z)
  e.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @connexo,in my password Textbox accepting numbers, alphabets and only @ symbol but i want to accept all special characters in my textbox except spaces.

Answer (score 0):

[`charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) is non-standard, deprecated, and not foreseen for `keydown` events, it may be available, but always 0.

[`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is also deprecated.

Use `e.key`:

```js
const accepted = " ,;!?";
function allowAlphaNumericSpace(e) {
  var code = e.key;
  if (isNaN(code) && code.toUpperCase() == code.toLowerCase() 
                  && !accepted.includes(code))  {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keydown", allowAlphaNumericSpace);
```

```html
<input>
```

If some other characters need to be accepted, it is easily adapted.